# Openstack Nova scheduler configure with ComputeCapabilitiesFilter

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I am trying to configure Nova scheduler to balancing workload between compute hosts. My OpenStack environment is deployed by kolla-ansible and has 2 compute nodes: compute1 with 8Gb RAM and compute2 with 16 Gb Ram. I want to use ComputeCapabilitiesFilter filter by adding this configure into `/etc/kolla/nova-schedular/nova.conf` configure file.

```
[filter_scheduler]
enabled_filters = ComputeFilter,ComputeCapabilitiesFilter,ImagePropertiesFilter,ServerGroupAntiAffinityFilter,ServerGroupAffinityFilter,SameHostFilter
capabilities:total_usable_ram_mb >= 12000
```

Then I restart nova-schedular docker container. But it doesn't seem to work because new instances still are allocated into compute1 which has only 8 Gb Ram. I can't determine whether the cause is a syntax error, configuration in the wrong place, or a system error.
I searched in every document of OpenStack, but it doesn't have any sample configure file to configure with ComputeCapabilitiesFilter.

Can anyone help me with a guide or give me some advices?

Answer (score 0):

This filter matches host atrributes with **flavor's extra_specs**, so I need to run `openstack flavor set m1.tiny --property total_usable_ram_mb=">= 12000"` with `m1.tiny` is flavor which be used to create instances.